# Send NSNotification on background thread in Appdelegate.m

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am receiving a remote notification.  I want to post a nsnotification.  I can post the notification, but I can't receive it in my current view controller.

Here is my code.

I know this gets called:

`AppDelegate.m`

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
 {

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CHAT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED object:nil userInfo:messageIdDict];

 }
```

This gets called before the above code gets called

`MyViewController.m`

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(messageReceived:)
                                             name:CHAT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED
                                           object:self];

 }

 -(void)messageReceived:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
 {
      NSLog(@"Logged");
 }
```

Comment: Change object to `nil` (instead of `self`).  The notification is not being fired with regards to your controller.  This matches the way you are posting it.

Comment: '- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo' in this method object should be the notification sender, precisely in your case self so your posting notification message should be as '[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CHAT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED object:self userInfo:messageIdDict];
'

Comment: I am waiting on someone, so that I can test this, but I suspect borrrden is right, I need to change the object to nil instead of self for the observer.  @suraj, do I need to change the object to self in the poster?  Does that make a difference?  I've tried that before with other `NSNotifications`, (but didn't think to change the observer) but I didn't notice a difference.

Comment: Your "MyViewController" should receives remote notification when it's on the screen? Why don't you put -addObserver to -viewDidLoad and -removeObserver to -viewDidUnload. Or even better to -init and -dealloc

Comment: The signature of your `messageReceived:` is wrong. It should be `-(void)messageReceived:(NSNotification *)notification`

Comment: sorry @KKendall I was miss understood it; borrrden is right while adding observer you should change object from self to nil because this is The object whose notifications the observer wants to receive and if you pass nil than you can observe all the notification with same Name (you given), sender doesn't metter.

Comment: @PeterWarbo thanks! That was my next issue!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i would do it:

In AppDelegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
 {

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CHAT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED              
                                                     object:messageIdDict 
                                                   userInfo:nil];

 }
```

In MyViewController:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(messageReceived:)
                                              name:CHAT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED
                                            object:nil];

 }

 -(void)messageReceived:(NSNotification *)notification
 {
      NSDictionary *userInfo = NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[notification object]];
      NSLog(@"Logged");
 }
```

Hope this helps